# Clear splash animation javascript returns undefined

Tags: javascript, animation, opacity, splash-screen

My clear animation works, my display animation works, but when I try to do one then the other it it seems to make all the programming null. I'm sure there is a simple argument that I'm just not seeing.

```
var opac = null;

var removeGif = document.getElementById('splash');
function dissappear (elem, speed) {
    if (opac) clearTimeout(opac);
    if ( !elem.style.opacity ) {
        elem.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
        elem.style.opacity -= 1;
        }, speed / 50);
    },10);
}
dissappear(removeGif, 250000);

var folio = document.getElementById('content');
function appear (elem, speed) {
    if (opac) clearTimeout(opac);
    if ( !elem.style.opacity ) {
        elem.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
        elem.style.opacity += 1;
        }, speed / 50);
    },10);
}
appear(removeGif, 250000);
```

If anyone can see the problem please let me know.

Comment: You never assign the result of `setTimeout` to `opac`, so `opac` will always be `null`. Should you be doing something different there?

Comment: If you're trying to animate the element "disappearing" and "appearing", why are you incrementing/decrementing the opacity by `1` - the opacity's value can be anywhere from `0` to `1`, so you probably want a smaller value. And I'm not sure you're doing something correctly with your `setInterval`s - they will run forever because you never clear them. And as Cory pointed out, this shouldn't work at all because you're not actually setting `opac` anywhere. If you set `opac`, then it works, but it will be a flash of disappearing, not gradual.

Comment: I want the swap to be instant after 250000 milliseconds so no fade is no problem. Do i even need an interval or timeout?

Comment: @horribly_n00bie: If you don't want the "fade" effect then you would not need the interval. You probably wouldn't need the timeout either, just run three steps in quick succession: (1) get references to the splash and the content, (2) hide the splash, then (3) show the content. You will have to decide what to do if it seems like it flickers too dramatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of things that might be problematic:

1. You never assign the result of `setTimeout` to `opac`, so `opac` will always be `null`.

   ```
   opac = setTimeout(function() {
              ...
          });
   ```
2. In `appear()`, this block of code doesn't make sense to me:

   ```
   if ( !elem.style.opacity ) {
       elem.style.opacity = 0;
   }
   ```

   Can `elem.style.opacity` be null? If so, then it's ok. `!elem.style.opacity` will also be true if the opacity is `0`, so it would be unecessary to reset it to 0.

   Wouldn't you want to check if the element is already visible and then break out of the function instead of turning it invisible first?
3. As [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317927/ian) said, opacity values range from 0 to 1 as a decimal value, not a percentage value. Consider changing the increment and decrement to something like 0.1.
4. Your `setInterval()` functions will never stop running. You never have any corresponding `clearInterval()`. Nor do you ever check that the opacity is 0 or 1 to know when to call `clearInterval()`.

A simple fadein/fadeout implementation shouldn't need a `setTimeout`. A working example [looks more like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909750/74757).

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to check `if (elem.style.opacity)`, then set it to `0` if so. But I don't even think that makes sense. If it's in the middle of the opacity range, let it start "appearing" from that value - no need to reset it.

Comment: Well the content opacity is supposed to start out as 0 the become 1 at the same time as the splash goes from opacity 1 to 0.so it has the illusion that the splash animation turns into the content.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input to help me make my code not so circuitous. Here is the code I ended up with.

```
window.setTimeout(function toggle () {
    var spl = document.getElementById('splash');
    var cnt = document.getElementById('content');
        spl.style.display = "none";
        cnt.style.display = "block";
}, 25000);
```

It all seems so simple now!

Comment: FYI: You don't even need to (nor should you) name your function: `window.setTimeout(function() { /* do work */ }, 25000);`

Comment: Followup... actually, what you probably should do, is define `toggle()` as a regular function, and then simplify your code to: `window.setTimeout(toggle, 25000);`.